# creating nested list without using zip

Tags: python, list, nested

I want to create a nested list from to lists I already have so that I can loop through them for an sql query script and use each element as a variable.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = ['a','b','c','d']
```

and I want

`c = [1,['a'],2,['b'],3,['c'],4,['d']]`

I tried using `zip` but it did not give me the order I need

Comment: Why do you need the letters to being inside a single-element list?

Comment: so i can loop through them to use as variables in an `UPDATE` sql query within my function

Comment: .... but they are a single element...? Why would you need to *loop* through them?

Comment: they represent two lists I have in my function, they are not the actual lists i have, when i run my `UPDATE` on is the list of primary keys in column 1 and the other list is made up of some numbers that i want to update into column 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[i for x, y in zip(a, b) for i in [x, [y]]]

# [1, ['a'], 2, ['b'], 3, ['c'], 4, ['d']]
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be a more elegant way of doing this with interpolation, but a pretty simple solution is:

```
l = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    l.append(a[i])
    l.append([b[i]])
```

Comment: Just use `for e1, e2 in zip(a, b)`